# subquery in oracle sql

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, subquery

i have 2 accounts, and i want to create an output that will give me all the names of acct 1 with the respective weight of ppl in acct 1, i also want it to then pull in all the names for acct 2 that match acct 1, ie acct 2 has other names but i only care about it displaying the weights with names that appear in acct 1.

my current oracle sql query has to include a join as well, so currently i created:

*SELECT *
FROM
(select names
from acct_table
JOIN name_attrib ON name_attrib.id = acct_table.id
WHERE acct_table.acctno = 1) acct1_names*

this gives me the first part, i now have a list of names just from table 1, but im unclear how i now go about incorporating a query that would then pull in weights (which sit in the acct_table table) for acctno 2.

Comment: realized i could just run the query on acct 2 and use where IN and use the query from above. This works up to a point but it then is showing me where there is an exact match, but i would also like to see the names that are present in acct 1 that are not present in acct 2

Comment: Sample data would certainly help (as well as desired output).